# Retornar ID da tag pai ao clicar em um botão

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um conjunto de botões onde quero retornar o ID da tag pai quando um botão for clicado para implementar uma função.

```
<div id="botoes">
  <button data-for="cod" onclick="checkbox(this)">cod</button>
  <button data-for="nome" onclick="checkbox(this)">nome</button>
  <button data-for="barras" onclick="checkbox(this)">barras</button>
  <button data-for="desc" onclick="checkbox(this)">desc.</button>
</div>
```

como faço isso? Meu "google-fu" não me ajudou...

Comment: Você quer ter acesso ao id de "botoes" de dentro da função `checkbox`, é isso?

Comment: não, a função checkbox é apenas o nome dela.. ela faz outra coisa nem era necessária estar ai.

Comment: Uai, então não entendi por que você aceitou a resposta abaixo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o `parentElement` para obter o elemento `DOM` relativo ao pai.
O `parentNode` é apenas por compatibilidade com browsers muito antigos, mas pode ser removido.

```
function checkbox(child) {
    var parent = child.parentElement || child.parentNode;
    var id = parent.getAttribute('id');
}
```

Mais detalhes: [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node.parentElement) e [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode)

Comment: valeu pela informação... acabei reformulando a lógica do sistema para ficar mais plausível...

Answer (score 1):

Sei que já faz algum tempo que a pergunta foi postada, no entanto, fica como forma de aprendizagem para os demais que por aqui passarem :-)

Neste caso, você poderia usar um recurso do jQuery: o `.parent()`.

Ele, assim como o `.closest()` servem para a questão, no entanto, como você deseja simplesmente pegar o elemento pai sem nenhuma especificação (via id ou classe), sugiro o `.parent()`.

Ficaria assim ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rn19eq2g/)):

```
function checkbox(btn){
  var idParent = $(btn).parent().attr('id'); 
  alert(idParent);
}
```

Ou se preferir um javascript puro ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2nmra5ad/)):

```
function checkbox(btn) {
    var idParent = btn.parentElement.id || btn.parentNode.id;
    alert(idParent);
}
```

Fica a dica.